# Exposing relational models to backgrid.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational, backgrid

I want to expose some attributes from relational model (builded via backbone-relational) to my backgrid (builded via backgrid.js). As I understand backgrid receives collection and mapped model as columns object. So I need to change model when the model initialised, e.g. something like:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.fetchRelated('myRelatedModel');
  this.set({relatedName:this.get('myRelatedModel').get('name')});
}
```

The problem is that when I do this, my model receives 'changed' state. But I don't want to change model, I only want to expose related model's attributes to my backgrid.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JavaScript**

```
this.set({relatedName:this.get('myRelatedModel').get('name')}, {silent: true});
```